# Error when creating a tournament schedule

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am making a tournament schedule based on permutation, but I want to be able to update the schedule with new matches, if a new player joins the league.

My code as seen below currently throws an error:

```
"in update': undefined method `[]' for 2014-04-04 11:00:00 +0200:Time (NoMethodError)"

require 'pp'
require 'set'

def schedule(players)
    matchups = players.permutation(2)
    matches = []
    matchups.each do |matchup|  
        unless matches.include?(matchup.reverse)
            matches << matchup
        end
    end
    matches.each do |match|
        match << time
    end
    matches
end

def time
    now = Time.now
    a_week_ahead = now + 60 * 60 * 24 * 7
    random_time = rand(now..a_week_ahead)
    random_time -= random_time.min * 60 + random_time.sec
end

# The map methods is to cut off the date for each match when checking for duplicates

def update(original, updated)
    updated.each do |match|
        original << match unless original.map{ |match| match[0..1]}.include?(match.map{ |match| match[0..1] })
    end     
    original
end

update(schedule(('A'..'H').to_a), schedule(('A'..'I').to_a))
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `match.map` after your `include?` is returning all three elements of the array, including the date.

Try this - creating `match` as an array of arrays in your `include?` criteria:

```
def update(original, updated)
  updated.each do |match|
    original << match unless original.map{ |match| match[0..1]}.include?([match].map{ |match| match[0..1] })
  end     
  original
end
```

Just an edit - I think this should give you the same results as well and it's a touch easier without the second `map`:

```
def update(original, updated)
  updated.each do |match|
    original << match unless original.map{ |match| match[0..1]}.include?(match[0..1])
  end     
  original
end
```